# Changing Textview Dynamicly after a certain period of Days

Tags: android, textview, days

I'm quite new to Android and I want to change (I know how to set it dynamically but....)Textview Dynamically after a certain period of Days,but int the meantime keep the text posted unless changed by user or if a certain days have been reached by my program.

Well Basically I have the user to input a Date  then i want my program to count days and as long as the user nor my program have intervene with the textview it will show the same text and backround color until the opposite is taken action.

here is my code:

```
 String CurrentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
    String FinalDate = TvDateOfService.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dateinput;
    Date datetwra;
    //Setting dates
    try {
        dateinput = dates.parse(FinalDate);
        datetwra = dates.parse(CurrentDate);


        //Comparing dates
        long difference = Math.abs(dateinput.getTime() - datetwra.getTime());
        long differenceDates = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        //Convert long to String
        String dayDifference = Long.toString(differenceDates);

        //Calendar Instance to Add 89 Days for Service Period Between Dates!!
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 90);
        Date ServicePeriod = cal1.getTime();

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 80);
        Date DaysBeforeEnd = cal2.getTime();

        do {
            tvStatus.setBackground(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_backround_green));

        }while (dateinput.before(DaysBeforeEnd));

        do {
            tvStatus.setText("something");
            tvStatus.setBackground(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_backround_yellow));
        }while (dateinput.after(DaysBeforeEnd));

        do {
            tvStatus.setText("something else");
            tvStatus.setBackground(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_backround_red));
        }while (dateinput.after(ServicePeriod));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a for loop and wait a certain number of days - it would be most beneficial to the phone's battery if you used AlarmManager

https://developer.android.com/trai.../scheduling/alarms.html